# Yaml to JSON conversion on database.yml skips some special functionality

Tags: json, yaml, converters

trying to convert the about yml to json . When I try to do it it is skipping &,<<,*. I have tried a bunch of things but it does not seem to create json as I expected.

I am trying to use node to convert yml to json and vice versa.

```
development-mysql: &development-mysql
  pool: 5
  encoding: utf8
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 1234

alpha: &alpha
  <<: *development-mysql
  adapter: oracle
  database: testDB
  username: test
  time_zone: UTC
```

converts to

```
{
  "development-mysql": {
    "pool": 5,
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 1234
  },
  "alpha": {
    "pool": 5,
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 1234,
    "adapter": "oracle",
    "database": "testDB",
    "username": "test",
    "time_zone": "UTC"
  }
}
```

which when I try to convert it back to yml is like this

```
development-mysql:
    pool: 5
    encoding: utf8
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 1234
alpha:
    pool: 5
    encoding: utf8
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 1234
    adapter: oracle
    database: testDB
    username: test
    time_zone: UTC
```

now in theory this is correct but we kind of lost the capability of <<,* and & . Any way to have json with all the capability retained and convert it back to yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using anchors and aliases (`&` / `*`) or the merge key (`<<`) which isn't even defined in the YAML spec, but as an [optional extension](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html), you are using features that simply do not exist in JSON.

The merge key type (`<<`) is even defined as *merging* the mappings, meaning that if you load a document using this feature, even if you write it back as YAML, you will get the merged map printed out because it is processed while loading the document. You could only circumvent this by using an implementation that does not actually process the merge key (not all do).

With anchors and aliases, the simple truth is that JSON does not offer anything like it. That means that if you serialize a value to JSON where any sub-node is referred to multiple times, the JSON implementation has no choice but to copy the value.

Now of course there is a remedy. That remedy would be to serialize the *structure* (instead of the constructed value) of the YAML input as JSON. Let's have a look at this simple YAML example:

```
- &a foo
- *a
```

The resulting JSON could look something like this:

```
{
  "type": "sequence",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "scalar",
      "anchor": "a",
      "value": "foo"
    }, {
      "type": "alias",
      "target": "a"
    }
  ]
}
```

This JSON representation preserves all information of the original YAML file and thus the YAML input can be rebuilt from it. But the JSON gets quite stuffed since we need to encode the structural information of the YAML input into objects. The question is whether the JSON is useful for whatever stuff you are trying to do with it.

If this is a feasible approach, you will need to implement it. First you need a YAML implementation that gives you access to the low-level event tree as per YAML spec (not all do), see this diagram:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaml.org](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/overview2.png))</sub>

What is called an *event tree* is, in most implementations, actually an event list, consisting of events like *StartSequence*, *EndSequence* etc. You  will need to write code to encode this list into JSON and also code to decode the JSON back to the list, which you can then stuff back into the YAML implementation to get the result as you want to have it.

Now chances are that this is far too much effort for what you actually want to do. I strongly advice against doing this and finding a way to deal with whatever problem you're solving without converting YAML to JSON while requiring it to preserve YAML features that are missing in JSON.